# Create Object without assigning it to var inside function scope

Tags: javascript

I know that when I assign an object to a variable inside a function without declaring it with `var` it becomes a global.

But what happens when I create a new object without assigning it to anything. For example like:

```
(function(){
 new Foo();
})();
```

I found this question:  [Is it bad practice to not assign a new object to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594415/is-it-bad-practice-to-not-assign-a-new-object-to-a-variable)
but this does not have any technical details on how it can introduce memory leaks.

Comment: What does the `Foo()` constructor do? If it doesn't affect anything other than its own state, e.g. setting some internal properties, then what's the point?

Comment: My main point is, could it introduce a memory leak if the created object reference another object ?

Comment: No. That won't create a memory leak.